# string to named function argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to do the following in python: 
There is this function which takes named arguments.

```
def functionA(self, input1, argument2='', argument3='',argument4='DefaultVal'):
## do something
```

My input string is via command line and should look like this

```
testcommand test1 argument2=test2 argument3=test3
```

This should resolve to the call the above function using the named arguments. What would be the easiest way

Comment: I'd probably use the [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse#module-argparse) stdlib module, but you could certainly do it yourself with `sys.argv`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, with limited error checking, but I definitely recommend checking out [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html):

```
import sys

# To simulate arguments
sys.argv = ['<script>', 'foo', 'test1', 'arg2=test2', 'arg3=test3']

# An example of a function that you want to call
def foo(input1, arg2='', arg3='', arg4='default'):
    print("foo called:")
    print(input1, arg2, arg3, arg4)

# Add callable functions to a dict
CALLABLES = {'foo': foo}

def call_callable(argv):
    args = []                       # A list for positional arguments
    kwargs = {}                     # A dict for keyword arguments
    func = CALLABLES[argv[0]]       # Get callable by name (may raise KeyError)
    # Parse remaining arguments into either args or kwargs
    for arg in argv[1:]:
        if '=' in arg:
            kwargs.update((arg.split('='),))
        else:
            args.append(arg)

    # Call function, return it's result to the script (if it matters)
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

# Slice argv to ignore the first (script) element
call_callable(sys.argv[1:])
```

The argument processing is straightforward, building a list for positional arguments and a dictionary for keyword arguments, then unpacking them into the `func()` call.

I also created a `CALLABLES` dict that will allow you to access functions by name in a safer way than going through `globals()`.